# I want to setup a cron job in my redhat machine

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I want to setup a cron job on my redhat server. How can I do that?

I do not understand the concept of timing specification there.

Comment: If you google this, you will find hundreds of links explaining how you can achieve it. If you run into any issues please ask specific problem and not something so generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a shell script in one of these folders: `/etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.monthly or /etc/cron.weekly.`

If these are not enough, you can add more specific tasks eg. twice a month or every 5 minutes or... go to the terminal and type:

```
crontab -e
```

this will open your personal crontab (cron configuration file), the first line in that file explains it all (don't you think)! In every line you can define one command to run, and the format is quite simple when you get the hang of it. So the structure is:

minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week command
For all the numbers you can use lists eg, 5,34,55 in the first field will mean run at 5 past 34 past and 55 past what ever hour is defined.

You can also use intervals, they are defined like this: */20 this example means every 20th and if in the minutes column this will be equivalent to 0,20,40
So to run a command every monday at 5:30 in afternoon:

30 17 * * 1 /path/to/command
or every 15 minutes

*/15 * * * * /path/to/command
Note that the day-of-week goes from 0-6 where 0 is sunday.